# Can we update the textbox value in validation process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf and xaml,but have been reading few tutorials online and learning.I have created a textbox and added validation rule by deriving from ValidationRule class and overriding Validate method.

So in that method I make sure string entered is not empty else I return `new ValidationResult(false, "Input required");`

Now can I update the text value here;for example if the string is empty set it to a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, validation rules happens outside of the logical tree.

You can try [Josh Smith's virtual branch](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18678/Attaching-a-Virtual-Branch-to-the-Logical-Tree-in) approach.